# group by on a column and get the sum of that column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table :

```
------------------------------------
ReportDate  | DAGName | MailboxCount
------------------------------------
```

There is lot of records in this table . I have to get the sum of mailboxcount of each dagName on the 1st day of every month for a particular year.

```
------------------------------------
ReportDate  | DAGName | MailboxCount
------------------------------------
01-01-2012  | abc     |  25
01-02-2012  | xyz     |  55
01-02-2012  | abc     |  125
01-03-2012  | lmn     |  225
01-01-2012  | ghf     |  325
01-03-2012  | kil     |  525
11-03-2012  | kil     |  525
21-03-2012  | kil     |  625
10-05-2012  | jil     |  225
20-11-2012  | kil     |  1525
04-03-2012  | Mil     |  5025
```

So what i want as the result is

```
---------------------------------
Month Name     | Count
---------------------------------
 January       | 350
 Ferbuary      | 150
 March         | 850
```

My Query

```
SELECT SUM(MailboxCount) AS Count,DagName
              ,MONTH(CAST(ReportDate AS DATETIME))
              ,DATENAME(month, ReportDate)  AS 'Month Name'
        FROM MailboxDatabase
        WHERE (CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [ReportDate], 103), 103)
        IN ( '01/01/'+ @year,'01/02/'+ @year,
             '01/03/'+ @year,'01/04/'+ @year,
             '01/05/'+ @year,'01/06/'+ @year,
             '01/07/'+ @year,'01/08/'+ @year,
             '01/09/'+ @year,'01/10/'+ @year,
             '01/11/'+ @year,'01/12/'+ @year 
            ))
        GROUP BY  MONTH(CAST(ReportDate AS DATETIME)),DATENAME(month, ReportDate),DagName  
        ORDER BY 2
```

I am fine if some extra columns like coming with my query. But it is not giving me the correct result. Any help ??

Comment: remove DagName its not part of your grouping, reportDate is of what type isn't it a datetime

Comment: Do not EVER use `VARCHAR` without specifying a length, or it will come back and haunt you.

Comment: no it is not as date is not the first day of month....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be completely misinterpreting the question but wouldn't the following suffice?

```
  SELECT  [Month Name] = DATENAME(month, ReportDate), [Count] = SUM(MailboxCount)
  FROM    MailboxDatabase
  WHERE   DAY(ReportDate) = 1
          AND YEAR(ReportDate) = 2012
  GROUP BY
          DATENAME(month, ReportDate)
```

**Test script**

```
;WITH MailboxDatabase AS (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
      ('01-01-2012', 25)
    , ('02-01-2012', 55)
    , ('02-01-2012', 125)
    , ('03-01-2012', 225)
    , ('01-01-2012', 325)
    , ('03-01-2012', 525)) AS X(ReportDate, MailboxCount)
)
  SELECT  [Month Name] = DATENAME(month, ReportDate)
          , [Count] = SUM(MailboxCount)
          , Month = MONTH(ReportDate)
  FROM    MailboxDatabase
  WHERE   DAY(ReportDate) = 1
          AND YEAR(ReportDate) = 2012
  GROUP BY
          DATENAME(month, ReportDate), MONTH(ReportDate)
  ORDER BY
          MONTH(ReportDate)
```

Comment: it is almost there but what i need is on the first day with group by of groups tooo

Comment: @ankur - That I don't understand. Can you clarify by adding the requirement to your posted example *(ps. the count's in your example are off)*

Comment: Not really, adding those records doesn't alter the result of the statement I've posted but I'm not sure if you want another result or not. Did you try the statement?

Comment: @ankur - I have added an order by the simplest way I see possible (by adding a month column). Another option would be to add a searched order by (using a case statement).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105)) Month, 
       SUM(MailboxCount) COUNT
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105))
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd04c/8)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with ORDER BY* clause)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cd04c/15)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105)) Month, 
       SUM(MailboxCount) COUNT
FROM   tableName
WHERE  (CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105), 103)
        IN ( '01/01/'+ '2012','01/02/'+ '2012',
             '01/03/'+ '2012','01/04/'+ '2012',
             '01/05/'+ '2012','01/06/'+ '2012',
             '01/07/'+ '2012','01/08/'+ '2012',
             '01/09/'+ '2012','01/10/'+ '2012',
             '01/11/'+ '2012','01/12/'+ '2012' 
            ))
GROUP  BY MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105)),
          DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105))
ORDER  BY MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105))
```

Comment: the result are correct but there is no condition for date , since there will be lot of records of other dates too..

Comment: FYI, the table name is MailboxDatabase

Comment: @SenJacob does it really matter on the demo? `:)`

Comment: JW can you inculde some random dates in your demo, that are not the first day of any month though have the same DAG name to test, if it work i can mark it as solved.....

Comment: i meant this  
INSERT INTO Tablename
 ([ReportDate], [DAGName], [MailboxCount])
VALUES
 ('01-01-2012', 'abc', 25),
 ('01-02-2012', 'xyz', 55),
 ('01-02-2012', 'abc', 125),
 ('01-03-2012', 'lmn', 225),
 ('01-01-2012', 'ghf', 325),
 ('01-03-2012', 'kil', 525),
    ('20-11-2012', 'kil', 525),
    ('11-07-2012', 'kil', 525),
    ('31-03-2012', 'kil', 525),
    ('21-03-2012', 'kil', 525),
    ('11-03-2012', 'kil', 525)
; and it is not working correctly

Comment: what is your expected output for that certain record? see again this link, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/695ed/1

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      ReportDate DATETIME
    , DAGName NVARCHAR(50)
    , MailboxCount INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (ReportDate, DAGName, MailboxCount)
VALUES 
    ('01-01-2012',  'abc', 25),
    ('01-02-2012',  'xyz', 55),
    ('01-02-2012',  'abc', 125),
    ('01-03-2012',  'lmn', 225),
    ('01-01-2012',  'ghf', 325),
    ('01-03-2012',  'kil', 525),
    ('11-03-2012',  'kil', 525),
    ('21-03-2012',  'kil', 625),
    ('10-05-2012',  'jil', 225),
    ('20-11-2012',  'kil', 1525),
    ('04-03-2012',  'Mil', 5025)

DECLARE @year INT = 2012

SELECT 
      [Count] = SUM(MailboxCount)
    , Month_Name = DATENAME(MONTH, ReportDate)
FROM @temp
WHERE DAY(ReportDate) = 01 
    AND YEAR(ReportDate) = @year
GROUP BY ReportDate
ORDER BY ReportDate
```

**Output:**

```
Count       Month_Name
----------- ------------------------------
350         January
180         February
750         March
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105)) AS [MonthName],
      YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105)) AS [Year],
      SUM(MailboxCount) COUNT
FROM tableName
GROUP BY 
      DATENAME(MONTH, CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105)),
      YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, ReportDate, 105))
```

Try above sql query, this query return the result with year wise month and count.